PsExec launch remote program as same user name without a domain
I'm trying to launch a remote program with PsExec. I have it mostly working, it works if I specify the user name and password or I run as SYSTEM account.
I want to omit the user name and password, so that it just runs with the same account PsExec was executed in.
I'm guessing this is failing because there is no domain, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work without one?
The account on both machines are using a local account with the same user name and password.
Commands that work:
.\psexec64 \\192.168.250.31 -u username -p password -d -i 2 notepad.exe

.\psexec64 \\192.168.250.31 -s -d -i 2 notepad.exe

Command that doesn't work:
.\psexec64 \\192.168.250.31 -d -i 2 notepad.exe


Unfortunately, what you are attempting to accomplish doesn't appear to be possible, since PsExec is a Microsoft Product, after all.
As a result, it's fairly safe to assume  that Microsoft probably isn't going to make a tool freely available to the public, if it can be used to circumvent security measures in their own Operating Systems, etc.
On the other hand, if you want to specify a Local User Account without a Domain, I would try the PC Name, first.
psexec -u PC-NAME\localaccount -d -i 2 notepad.exe

If that doesn't work, you can give Dot Notation a try.
psexec -u .\localaccount -d -i 2 notepad.exe

